# Nothing is being rendered if I add imports

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-charts

This is my component.ts :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'bancaComponent',
  template: `
                <ng-container #dynamicTemplate></ng-container>
              `
})
export class BancaComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {
  @ViewChild('dynamicTemplate', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: false }) dynamicTemplate;
  BarChartDataInput = [
    {
      "name": "Germany",
      "value": 40632,
      "extra": {
        "code": "de"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "United States",
      "value": 50000,
      "extra": {
        "code": "us"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "France",
      "value": 36745,
      "extra": {
        "code": "fr"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "United Kingdom",
      "value": 36240,
      "extra": {
        "code": "uk"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Spain",
      "value": 33000,
      "extra": {
        "code": "es"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Italy",
      "value": 35800,
      "extra": {
        "code": "it"
      }
    }
  ];
  constructor(private _compiler: Compiler,
    private _injector: Injector,
    private _m: NgModuleRef<any>) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    let myTemplateUrl = `<p>test</p>`;

    const tmpCmp = Component({
      moduleId: module.id, template: myTemplateUrl
    })(class {
    });
    const tmpModule = NgModule({imports: [NgxChartsModule, BrowserModule, CommonModule, BrowserAnimationsModule]
      , declarations: [tmpCmp] })(class {
    });

    this._compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(tmpModule)
      .then((factories) => {
        const f = factories.componentFactories[0];
        const cmpRef = f.create(this._injector, [], null, this._m);
        cmpRef.instance.name = 'dynamic';
        this.dynamicTemplate.insert(cmpRef.hostView);
      });
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

I want to render a dynamic template which has ngx-charts but in the NgModule I need to add required imports for the ngx-charts to work, if I remove the imports array then normal tags are being rendered but upon adding any imports nothing is being displayed and no error in console. How can I fix this?